# setRequestProperty method giving java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot set method after connection is made

Tags: java, android, httpconnection

```
HttpURLConnection con = null;
        Response response = new Response();
        String TAG = "HttpConHandler";

        try{
            /*
             * IMPORTANT: 
             * User SHOULD provide URL Encoded Parms
             */
            Log.p(TAG, "URL="+ urlStr);
            String q=httpHeaders.get("Authorization");

            URL url = new URL(urlStr);
            con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 

            con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", q);
            con.setRequestProperty("GData-Version", "3.0");
```

Hi I am getting `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot set method after connection is made` error when `setRequestProperty` method is called ,but when I call this method before connection I get `NullPointerException` because `con` is null. What can I do to solve this?

Comment: seems pretty clear.open the connection after you set your properties

Comment: @Ovidiu Latcu but i get a nullpointer exception cause con is not initialized

Comment: The code you have posted does not behave as described. You aren't calling `setResponseCode()`, which is a servlet method, not an `HttpURLConnection` method, and you aren't changing the method of the connection either, as suggested by the exception message. Clearly the real problem is that you are calling `setRequestProperty()` or `setRequestMethod()` or `getOutputStream()` in some other manner. Please post the real code.

Comment: It's the debugger: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22320418/setrequestproperty-throwing-java-lang-illegalstateexception-cannot-set-request[enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22320418/setrequestproperty-throwing-java-lang-illegalstateexception-cannot-set-request)

Answer (score 1):

Please check this URL from Google : http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

It is ok to use the `openConnection()` method before setting your headers. Here are the steps from the documentation:

1. Obtain a new HttpURLConnection by calling URL.openConnection() and casting the result to HttpURLConnection.
2. Prepare the request. The primary property of a request is its URI. Request headers may also include metadata such as credentials, preferred content types, and session cookies.
3. Optionally upload a request body. Instances must be configured with `setDoOutput(true)` if they include a request body. Transmit data by writing to the stream returned by `getOutputStream()`.
4. Read the response. Response headers typically include metadata such as the response body's content type and length, modified dates and session cookies. The response body may be read from the stream returned by `getInputStream()`. If the response has no body, that method returns an empty stream.
5. Disconnect. Once the response body has been read, the `HttpURLConnection` should be closed by calling `disconnect()`. Disconnecting releases the resources held by a connection so they may be closed or reused.

However if the problem persists you can either try to debug you code and check the connection.connected private flag to see where it becomes true; I've experienced a similar problem after making a call to the `getContentType()` method.

Otherwise you can just switch to HttpClient API:

```
  HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    // Prepare a request object
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url); 

    // Execute the request
    HttpResponse response;
    try {
        response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use URL's convenience method, either use an [HttpURLConnection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) or other library.

Comment: sorry didnt quiet get u..m alredy using HttpURLConnection..do u mean that i should not user url.openConnection

Comment: @Dennis Yes; openConnection uses its own connection and opens it, like the method name implies.

Comment: @Dennis Maclema's answer might be better; not sure.

Answer (score 0):

This may work:

```
URL url = new URL(urlStr);
con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
con.setDoOutput(true);
con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", q);
con.setRequestProperty("GData-Version", "3.0");
```

Comment: I am not sure if setting doOutput requires you to also open an OutputStream and actually write data, would require some playing around. Maybe checkout this post too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026260/java-how-to-use-urlconnection-to-post-request-with-authorization/2026299#2026299

Comment: didnt work still the same exception  now for con.setDoOutput(true);

Comment: Looks like on Android you cannot do this.. See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979087/how-can-i-use-http-auth-information-from-a-url-in-android