# setRequestProperty throwing java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot set request property after connection is made

Tags: android

I am getting `java.lang.IllegalStateException`:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException`: Cannot set request property after connection is made error when `setRequestProperty` method is called after 
`url.openConnection();`

Here is what i am trying:

```
URL url = new URL("https://49.205.102.182:7070/obsplatform/api/v1/mediadevices/545b801ce37e69cc");
         urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url
        .openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
```

any suggestions please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use this line  "urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/json");"before creating an Object and adding Url parameter.

Comment: @Amar Raj please do no give wrong answer

Comment: please look this link for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests

Comment: @AmarRaj i checked the link. there also setting properties after connection created(opened).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This usually happens if you have in the debug watchers calls, such as `conn.getResponseCode()` or anything that queries the request result before the request was actually issued or completed.
This causes, that during debug, a request is performed by the watcher, before having properly set you request, and then it becomes invalid.

Comment: Thank you! This should be accepted as the correct answer.

Comment: DEBUG WATCHER ! remove DEBUG WATCHER variable

Comment: Yes I see this when trying to run the app using the android profiler. Kind of frustrating, not sure how I can proceed

Answer (score 5):

I only have this issue while in debugging mode,
Run without debugging (You can print logs) everything should work fine

Comment: I only have this issue while in debugging mode - so do I

Comment: I have this issue in non-debugging mode also!

Comment: @SreekanthKarumanaghat Check for calls (including logging) that accesses functions like `getHeaderFields()` on the connection, as these can cause early-sending of the request. For me, this line was the culprit: `Log.i(TAG, "HeaderFields:" + conn.getHeaderFields());`

Answer (score 2):

The obvious thing is to think that you need to add properties before calling open on the URL. this however is not the case. i have seen many samples of settings being set AFTER url has been open (as counter intuitive as that is).

the problem in my case is that i had conn.getResponseCode() added in my watch list.  removed that and all good.

... tricky.

Answer (score 1):

please check below code

```
HttpURLConnection httpcon = (HttpURLConnection) ((new URL("a url").openConnection()));
httpcon.setDoOutput(true);
httpcon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
httpcon.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
httpcon.setRequestMethod("POST");
httpcon.connect();
```

Comment: Thanks for response, i tried but getting similar error java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already connected.

Comment: same question on stackoverflow see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726195/setresponsecode-method-giving-java-lang-illegalstateexception-cannot-set-method

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same exception on `setRequestProperty("Range","byte=" + downloadedSize + "-")` .
After adding `connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);` the issue disappeared

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue.
I was observing this issue on Nexus 5. Code of my app constantly fails with the same exception (or its twin brother "cannot set request method ..")

What I've observed that it happens if i leave phone for a while. One it starts failing it fails all the time - but if i restart phone/emulator it's ok once again).

My suspicion is its either some bug in connection pooling on framework side, or somewhere in code resources are leaked.

Answer (score 0):

i found the problem it's about ordering the code, if you are trying to add header and post parameters both, it's important to be careful about this

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlConnection;

////        Add Request Headers
for (NameValuePair nvp :
         request[0].getHeaderParams()) {
     connection.setRequestProperty(nvp.getName(),nvp.getValue());
     }
// done

connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
////         Add Post Parameters
OutputStream outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream));
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>(request[0].getPostParams());
bufferedWriter.write(getQuery(params));

// done
connection.setConnectTimeout(3000);
connection.setReadTimeout(3000);
bufferedWriter.flush();
bufferedWriter.close();
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
connection.connect();
```

in here, i have added header parameters then set `setDoInput` and `setDoOutput` then `setRequestMethod` and finally you can add POST parameters.
i don't know what is wrong with `setRequestMethod` but i think its preparing the connection by opening it or something and that's why it throws exception

Answer (score 0):

not invoke setRequestProperty after write byte to OutputStream.

```
OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
os.write("k=v".getBytes());
os.close();
```

you should invoke setRequestProperty  above the code

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot set request property after  connection is made

We have to check the connection response before access the request header fields :

```
URL url = new URL("https://49.205.102.182:7070/obsplatform/api/v1/mediadevices/545b801ce37e69cc");
     urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url
    .openConnection();

//Check connection
if(urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200/*Successful*/) {      
   urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
  ...
  ...    
 }
```